# Is there a Wordpress plugin which let the user register/login and see some new elements if he/she logs in?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Is there a Wordpress plugin which provides a full registration form for the user (name, phone, email, etc...)? (Once the user is logged in he/she will see new links in the navigation bar (or anywhere else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google for "**wordpress member plugin**"

some of popular plugin

- http://pennybutler.com/wordpress/plugin-reviews/wordpress-plugin-groups/20-wordpress-plugins-membership
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/member-access/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/